# topnavbar sticking not working on Chrome and Safary, but working on mozilla

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-chrome

I have a  topnavbar on my website page which actually get Fixed when the `$(window).scrollTop() > 44`. This working fine and looking good on Mozilla, but on safari and chrome its jumping when fixes the `topnavbar`. Any solutions?

This is my code:-

```js
//js
if(viewportWidth > 1199 && $(window).scrollTop() > 44){
    $('#topnavbar').addClass('topnavbarfixed');
}
```

```css
/*css*/
.topNavBar {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    background: #fff;
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(243, 243, 243, 0.88);
    z-index: 999 !important;
    padding: 0 !important;
}
.topnavbarfixed {
    position: fixed !important;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="topnavbar" class="topNavBar">
<!--Logo and some contents here -->
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.navBar {
  width: 100%; height: 6%;
  background-color: rgb(240, 240, 240);
  position: sticky;
  left: 0; top: 0;
  padding: 1%;
  overflow: auto;
}
.navBar a {text-decoration: none; margin-right: 1%;}

.emptySpace {width: 100%; height: 1000000px;}
```

```html
<span class="navBar">
  <a href="">Link 1</a>
  <a href="">Link 2</a>
  <a href="">Link 3</a>
  <a href="">Link 4</a>
  <a href="">Link 5</a>
</span>

<div class="emptySpace"></div>
```

I'm a bit confused as to what you're asking but if you're trying to get the navbar to stick to the top of the screen as the user scrolls you might want to try

```
/*CSS*/
.topNavBar {position: sticky;}
```

If that is not what you're looking for then please be a little more specific.

Hope this helps.